# Android prevent leaked windows

Tags: android, android-view

While running monkey tool on my app, I am getting ***android.view.WindowLeaked*** exception, I referred some stackoverflow threads and found that we need avoid ***this*** while creating popups, instead we need to use getApplicationContext() but this is causing ***BadTokenException***

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5597): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Again after searching through I found this answer which says

> One cause of this error may be trying to display an application
>   window/dialog through a Context that is not an Activity

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually window leaks because You don't use [showDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method in `Activity` but only using `Dialog.show()` method.

When dialog is displayed and configuration of Your `Activity` changes (eg. orientation change) dialog has not window to attach, and this results in leak of window.

If You use [Compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) You should use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of pure `dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind `WindowManager$BadTokenException` is that you keep showing `dialog` or `popupwindow` on the window whose context is not alive now.

So should always dismiss popup or dialog whenever you switch between activities or dismiss any activity.

Therefore you should probably call dilog.dismiss() in onPause method.

```
onPause()
{
dilog.dismiss()
}
```